# Python: convert list of dictionary keys containing timestamps into a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, datetime, timestamp

I have the following list:

```
[(Timestamp('2017-01-26 00:00:00'), -0.19),
 (Timestamp('2018-04-05 10:00:00'), -0.15)]
```

I want to change the keys from timestamps into strings and get the following list

```
['2017-01-26 00:00:00',
 '2018-04-05 10:00:00']
```

Can this be done with a single line of code?

Thank you.

Comment: Look into `strftime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
lst = [(Timestamp('2017-01-26 00:00:00'), -0.19),
       (Timestamp('2018-04-05 10:00:00'), -0.15)]

dt = [str(t[0]) for t in lst]
print(dt)

# Output
['2017-01-26 00:00:00', '2018-04-05 10:00:00']
```